# Textmate OSX Yosemite ruby 1.8

Tags: macos, textmate

After upgrading to the OSX Yosemite, Textmate's duplicate line command 
`ctrl+shift D` produces an error `warning: -K is specified; it is for 1.8 compatibility and may cause odd behavior`.

Previously, this was fixed by changing the `PATH` to `/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin`

But now this does not work. 

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You can install Ruby 1.8.7 via rbenv and add it to Textmate paths:

> PATH:
>   /Users/YOUR_NAME/.rbenv/versions/1.8.7-p249/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
>
> TM_RUBY: /Users/YOUR_NAME/.rbenv/versions/1.8.7-p249/bin/ruby

If you have problems with installing ruby 1.8.7 with errors such as:

> openssl_missing.h:68: error: conflicting types for 'HMAC_CTX_copy'

you can try to do **brew unlink openssl**. After successfully installing ruby you can link it back with **brew link openssl --force**

Good Luck!